# Print lines from first file if no match found in a particular column of second file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I require some help with finding the difference between 2 files using shell script.

The first file is a simple text file - *File1.txt*

```
A1 B1
C2 D2
E3 F3
G4 H4
I5 J5
K6 L6
```

The other is a *csv* file - *File2.csv*

```
"Line1";"BB";"ZZ";"12";"A1 B1";"190";"123";"1000";"qw1"
"Line2";"KH";"YY";"78";"K6 L6";"45";"546";"234";"sgsd4"
"Line3";"JJ";"LY";"77";"G4 H4";"32";"12";"213";"sdg12"
```

My requirement is to find if each of the lines in *File1.txt* is present in *File2.csv (in the 5th column)* and if not then write it to a separate text file say, *Result.txt*

So expected result in the *Result.txt* would be -

```
C2 D2
E3 F3
I5 J5
```

I have been trying with grep and diff and even with awk. But so far unable to get the required result

@triplee @ghoti .

Ok agreed, may be I should have given examples of the commands I was using.
At different times with awk I was -
using `$1` instead of `$0` or
not using the `{print}` or
with the option `-F';'` instead of `-F'";"'`.
I tried with `'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$5] > 0'`.

I tried using `comm 23`.
There were some examples, I don't remember now, with `grep` I found on various sites but were printing all the values in *File1.txt*

Comment: You should show us what you have tried even if it doesn't work.  If your attempt is completely hopeless, a different kind of answer is required than if you are 99% there.

Comment: +1 on tripleee's comment. What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'";"' 'FNR==NR    {a[$0];next}
                        {if ($5 in a) delete a[$5]}
             END        {for (i in a) {print i}}' file1 file2
```

we store the lines of the first file. When parsing the second one, we delete any of them found at the specific column. Finally we print what remained in the array.

or we could change the files order (this is probably faster):

```
awk -F'";"' 'FNR==NR {a[$5];next} !($0 in a) {print $0}' file2 file1
```

Comment: The second option has worked and pretty fast as well. I was trying with a similar awk command earlier, reckon I might have been making a small mistake.

Answer (score 1):

With `cut`, `sort` & `uniq`:

```
cut -d'"' -f 10 file2.txt | sort - file1.txt | uniq -u
```

Output:

```
C2 D2
E3 F3
I5 J5
```

Note: Given the format of *file2.txt*, the `cut` delimiter and field could be '`;`' and '`5`', but using '`"`' and '`10`' saves the extra step of filtering out *file2.txt*'s double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
grep -vf <(grep -Po '[A-Za-z]\d [A-Za-z]\d' File2.csv) File1.txt
```

The command inside parenthesis (`grep -Po '[A-Za-z]\d [A-Za-z]\d' File2.csv`) gets the patterns from csv file (I'm assuming they're always in the format above: "LetterNumberSpaceLetterNumber"). Its output is:

```
A1 B1
K6 L6
G4 H4
```

The second grep then checks if these patterns are in File1.txt and `-v` option inverts it, showing only the non-matched lines:

```
C2 D2
E3 F3
I5 J5
```

ps: note that `-P` option is to use Perl compatible regular expressions, so check if it's available in the *grep* version you're using.